# how to use for loop in this scenario using vba

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have 50 sheets in my excel
I want to sum All the numbers whose font is red in sheet 1 and put it in A1 cell. Sheet 2 in A2 and .....
How to do it with only one time run?

I did something but it's only doing it in one sheet and i have to do it 50 times!!!

Comment: Please share more details, some screenshots, and the code of *"I did something"*.

Answer (score 1):

- Loop through all cells in UsedRange
- Sum all cells which has red font

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, iSum, c As Range
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        iSum = 0
        For Each c In Sht.UsedRange
            If c.Font.color = vbRed And IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                iSum = iSum + c.Value
            End If
        Next
        Sht.Cells(1, 1).Value = iSum
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.UsedRange property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm175134)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)